# My Gui doesn't show output text after clicking button

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

here is a newbie with Python. 
I'm programming this simple GUI:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def print_name():
   return  'Here is Steve'

here_goes_text = print_name()

button = Button(root,text='Say hello',command = print_name)
button.pack()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(END,here_goes_text)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What I wish is that after I click the "Say hello" button the Gui show me "Hi I'm Steve" on the text widget below.
Unfortunately right now when I run the program it show me immediately "Hi I'm Steve" on the text below and if I click the "Say hello" button nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It shows it immediately because you're inserting it immediately (`text.insert(END,here_goes_text)`)

Comment: Hi Bryan Oakley, ok I get it. But I still don't know how to solve this kind of problem,

Comment: Move the line where you insert the text on button click inside the function that is called when the button is clicked. Additionally you can't expect any values to be returned after an event.

Answer (score 0):

your asking tkinter to load up print_name alongside tkinter....
try
using print ("here is steave") instead of 
return "here is steave"